# Проверка form_upload() в CodeIgniter

Tags: form, codeigniter

Здравствуйте. Скажите, как можно проверит выбрал ил пользователь файл или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не выбран файл или какая то ошибка то надо проверять error в массиве $_FILES

```
if ($_FILES['uploadfile']['error']!='4'{
   //do something
}
```

недавно делал на codeigniter проект и проверял таким образом:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $data = $_FILES['file'];
    if ($data['error']['photo'] != '4') {
        //my code
    }
}
```

Comment: а можно поподробнее?
public function index(){
  $img1 = array(
   'name' => 'file',
  );
  
  if (isset($_FILES['file'])){
         $data = $_FILES['file'];
           if ($data['error']['file']!='4'){
      echo 'err';
     }
     }else{
   echo form_open('/lol');
      echo form_upload($img1);
      echo '<input type="submit">';
      echo form_close();
  }
 }
я вот так сдела, и чего-то не работает....

Comment: зачем вы выводите сообщение об ошибке есть по условию проверяется что нет ошибки?)
    if ($data['error']['file']!='4'){
        echo 'err';
    }
в таком случае надо так:
if ($data['error']['file']=='4'){
           echo 'err';
       } else {
           //действия если нет ошибки
       }

Comment: разобрался

Answer (score 2):

---

```
if(!empty($_FILES['fileInputName'])) {
    //  your code here
}
else {
    //  no file
}
```

---